# Can Silverlight 3 OPEN SOCKETS?

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets

Can Silverlight 3 OPEN SOCKETS?

---

**If yes.**
 What do I need

- MSDN if there is any help on this.
- Open Source Libs/wrappers for encoding/decoding.
- Tutorials and blog articles on How to do it.

  ---

  **If no** I need where did you get the info from (link to MSDN or other official SL resource)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it can.

1. MSDN: 
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248(VS.95).aspx
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(VS.95).aspx
2. One of the light libs you might find useful:
   http://socketslight.codeplex.com
3. A couple of how-to-s:
   http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/04/13/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-sockets-part-ii.aspx
   http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/SocketsLight-Silverlight-Sockets-Framework.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, but only within a certain range of ports (4502-4534) and only if you can also host an appropriate cross-domain policy file on port 943 on the same server.
You've already got the MSDN link - here's an example application (for SL2, but should be similar in 3):

[Pushing Data to a Silverlight Client with Sockets Part 1][1]

Search Dan's blog for "socket" and you can find part 2 and how to create the policy server - SO won't let me post more than 1 link :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's the MSDN article on working with sockets:

[Working with Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: The yes should be implied by the article title.

Comment: It's a MSDN article about using Sockets with Silverlight 3.. so.. YES! ;)

Comment: Could you please post some Tutorials and blog articles on How to do it. (open up Socket in SL3)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/04/10/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-sockets-part-i.aspx)'s an article about using sockets in Silverlight and [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/SocketsLight-Silverlight-Sockets-Framework.aspx) is a link to framework simplifying that. Also a quick search on google **will** turn up useable results!